# I initialized my project in Github and it stopped working, I would be very happy if you could take a look at this question

Tags: javascript

```
PS C:\Users\Jahongir\Desktop\MyProjects\DEMO> yarn start 
yarn run v1.22.21
$ vite
error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The property 'options.env['npm_package_description']' must be a string without null bytes. Received '#\x00 \x00m\x00y\x00-\x00l\x00o\x00g\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00i\x00c\x00-\x00a\x00p\x00p\x00\r\x00 \x00'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at validateArgumentNullCheck (node:child_process:973:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (node:child_process:700:7)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:754:13)
    at C:\Users\Jahongir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:25735:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (C:\Users\Jahongir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:5540:28)
    at C:\Users\Jahongir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:25732:12
    at run (C:\Users\Jahongir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:43187:7)
    at BlockingQueue.maybePushConcurrencyQueue (C:\Users\Jahongir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:43202:7)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I installed Node Modules again and nothing worked.

Comment: Dumping an error message and stack trace is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is related to an invalid argument value in the environment options. Specifically, it seems to be related to the npm_package_description field in your environment options being a string with null bytes.

Hope this fixes the issue